# My P-values are way lower than I expected and can not build a proper power curve

Tags: r, simulation, curve

```
pval.dist.sim = function(n, sigma_x, rho, reps = 2500){
p = 5; sigma = sqrt(2)
beta = c(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.25, 0)
mu = 10
# generate vector for pvals
pval.list = numeric(reps)
for(r in 1:reps){
# generate design matrix
X = gen_X(n = n, p = 5, rho = rho, sigma_x = sigma_x, mu = mu)
# generate the XtXinv portion of equation
XtXinv = qr.solve(crossprod(X))
sqrtXtXinv55 = sqrt(XtXinv[5,5])
y = X %*% beta + rnorm(n = n)
beta.hat = XtXinv %*% crossprod(X, y)
sE = sqrt(sum((y - X %*% beta.hat)^2)/(n-p))
t.val = beta.hat[3]/(sE * sqrtXtXinv55)
pval.list[r] = 2 * pt(-abs(t.val), df = n - p)
}
return(pval.list)
}
```

Above is the pval.dist simulation.  I need to run this function to build my p.values to build my power curve

```
set.seed(3701)
# givens
p = 5; d = 2; mu = 10; sigmasqrd = 2; reps = 2500
n.list = seq(from=10, to=150, by=10)
# create a vector for the estimates of the power
est.power = numeric(length(n.list))
# create a vector for the left endpoints of the 95% CI
LB.list = numeric(length(n.list))
# create a vector for the right endpoints of the 95% CI
UB.list = numeric(length(n.list))
for(j in 1:length(n.list)){
# perform the test reps times
pvals = pval.dist.sim(n = n.list[j], sigma_x = 1.5, rho = 0.2, reps = reps )
# record the simulated estimate of the power
est.power[j] = mean(pvals<0.05)
# compute the 95% conf int 
bounds = binom.test(x=sum(pvals < 0.05), n = reps, conf.level = 0.95)$conf.int[1:2]
LB.list[j] = bounds[1]
UB.list[j] = bounds[2]
}
## plot the power curve estimation
plot(n.list, est.power, t = "l", xlab = "n",ylab = "Power")
```

I am having the issue that my pvalues, when plugged in, are drastically low.  I am getting values in the single digit percentage. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `gen_X()` do? Could you provide that?

Comment: does R not have indentation? This seems very hard to read without code formatting...